# Multiple datasets Count with IIF in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate, iif

I am trying to write an expression in SSRS which counts only specific data using IIF. I found the following solution:
`=Sum(IIF(Fields!Program.Value = "FC", Fields!QuantityToShip.Value, 0))`

The code above works but only when there is ONE dataset, while I have several.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!Mgroup.Value,"DataSet1"=303,1,0))
```

I get the aggregation error:

> Textbox refers directly to the field ‘Mgroup’ without specifying a dataset aggregate

I added a sum:

```
=Count(IIF(Sum(Fields!Mgroup.Value,"DataSet1")=303,1,0))
```

Still getting the same error.

Why is that?
What can I put instead of Sum? All I need is to count how many groups named 303 I have.

Comment: Do you want to count how many Mgroup name 303 from other dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you used has some sintax errors. The Count function only aggregate from the scoped Dataset.

Try this:

```
=LookupSet(303,Fields!Mgroup.Value,Fields!Mgroup.Value,"DataSet1").Length
```

Let me know if this helps you.